# Send an xml to js from a twig symfony2 view

Tags: javascript, php, xml, symfony, twig

I've trouble to send an xml to JS. When I try to, the JS just doens't answer. There is a weird error which seems to be because the variable is executed.
But I'm accually using raw so it should not... The xml is from a database but for the research I'll give it to you.

WARNING: it's only the begining of the file (4k chars)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

I hope you'll get some ideas! :)

```
<td onclick="showMap('{{ parcours.kml|raw }}')">test</td>
```

Thank you!

Comment: sure you have some javascript errors in console  :)

Comment: quick and dirty try: reverse the quotes, e.g `<td onclick='showMap("{{ parcours.kml|raw }}")'>test</td>`

Comment: as you see the escapation fails on the first xml attribute as it also uses single quotes

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work as it prints :  
")'>Test  
I don't quiet understand this behaviour. :/  
When I click, I get this error on the console :"SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" at a line which is in no way right (line 8 for the error vs 36 for the table).

Comment: you need t make sure that your xml is a string, show your showMap function, you use parseXml() ?

Comment: Well, it's a string because I get it directly from Doctrine and the database. I don't use parseXml() and I wont because it's not how I'll use the xml, I'm using a googleApi. There the problems is, I think, that the string is redden but the JS so it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the filter escape works.

```
<td onclick='showMap("{{ parcours.kml|escape }}")'>test</td>
```

The filter has an alias "e".